# How can I bring dynamic information to an ionic framework based card?

Tags: ionic4

I need to show dynamic information on an ionic framework based card.

Below is the code snippet:

```
<ion-row>
<ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let palabra of palabras | async; let i = 
index">

<ion-card clas="welcome-cards" (click)="reproducirSonido(palabra)">
  <ion-card-header (click)="toggleSection(i)" class="header">
      <ion-card-title class="ion-text-center">{{palabra.nombre}}</ion- 
card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content [ngClass]="{'detail-enabled': clicked[i], 'detail- 
off': !clicked[i]}">
                <ion-img [src]="palabra.imagen"></ion-img>
    </ion-card-content>      
</ion-card>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>

<!--.ts code-->
  toggleSection(i) {
 this.clicked[i] = !this.clicked[i];
 }
```

Comment: Code looks pretty fine - what's the error you're getting?

Comment: RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the data from services as Observable and declare data object as a instance of Observable interface;

Otherwise you can simply remove the `| async` pipe in your template.

However, you can implement the following:

```
fetchData(uuid){
  this.dataObject$ = this.afDb.object(`resource/${uuid}`).valueChanges();
}
```

`.valueChanges()` gives you an observable and will update automatically when a new value is emitted or an existing value is modified.